# Spark AR studio, get position of object in v100+

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I am super lost in the jungle that is the documentation of SparkAR. I am trying to get the coordinates of a plane inside of the script editor, to use in collider detection, but I can't seem to get the right results. I need a 2d vector output with the x and the y axis, but all documentation I could find was in lower versions. I am able to get the x position of an obejct using:

```html
plane4.worldTransform.x.monitor().subscribe(function (posX) {
  Diagnostics.log(posX.newValue);
});
```

But this only prints the x value and I want to use the coordinates inside of the Patch Editor using From Script. Anybody that can help me with this, is greatly appreciated.

Comment: BTW to monitor a signal value in Spark it is better to use Diagnostics.watch("posX", posX) instead of Diagnostics.log()

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the Global position of an object to use in the Patch Editor, you can just use the Global Transform patch. No need to use scripting.

[image: patch example]